# How can I calculate the (Cost vs. ROAS) forecast via the API?

Tags: return-value, google-ads-api, roi

I want to call the API to get the (Cost vs. ROAS) forecast.

It's visible on GA-FE, but the response object doesn't contain the ROAS or any value metric.

GA_FE:

[image: https://screenshot.googleplex.com/3X58disgfgU2a4H]

API:

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v11/ForecastMetrics?hl=en

Any idea how can I calculate the (Cost vs. ROAS) forecast.